# "Giving your Plugin its own CP Section" What about the CSS?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, css

I'm working on a plugin with it's own CP section as described in the docs [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/templates#giving-your-plugin-its-own-cp-section). What is the appropriate way to include CSS styling for that page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include CSS for your plugin one of two ways.

**1) Inline CSS**

You can include CSS snippets by using `{% includeCss myCss %}`. This is great if you are just wanting to include a few lines of CSS. Read more here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includecss

**2) Reference a Resource CSS file**

Usually contained in your /resources folder inside your plugin you can include a CSS file by using `{% includeCssResource "pluginName/styles.css" %}` You can read more here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/resources

Comment: I tried and got both ways working.  Thank you!